# How can I create an error handling page in ICEfaces (with Facelets)?

Tags: jsf, error-handling, facelets, icefaces

I need a little help creating a catch-all error handling page in my ICEfaces application. I'd like to present a user-friendly message along with an exception stack trace.

I can redirect to an error page using the following directive in web.xml:

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

However, I can't figure out how to get to the exception within error.xhtml. Is it stored in `request`, `session`, or somewhere else?

I'm using ICEfaces 1.8.0 (with Facelets) and JSF 1.2 (Sun RI). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

[get some stack trace info into a custom tomcat error 500 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712716/get-some-stack-trace-info-into-a-custom-tomcat-error-500-page)

http://josephmarques.wordpress.com/2009/04/27/custom-jsf-exception-handling/

http://www.nabble.com/Exception-handling-in-JSF-td15850273.html

http://softwareengineeringsolutions.com/thoughts/frameworks/JSF.Techniques-Error.Handling.htm

Comment: Thanks - the last link had the result I was looking for - the exception is found in #{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception']}. I probably should've known that :)